# Error: "ReferenceError: quotesCollection is not defined", upon submitting form - Mongodb Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my `server.js` file code, followed by the complete error message in the browser and after clicking the Submit button.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();

MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://star:wars123@clusterstar2.j9vfh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(client => {
        console.log('Connected to Database');
        const db = client.db('star-wars-quotes'); // "star-wars-quotes" is the db name
        const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes');
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    quotesCollection.insertOne(req.body)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'));
```

Below is the error seen:

```
ReferenceError: quotesCollection is not defined
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\server.js:28:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:101:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MERN\crud-express-mongo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Your object `quotesCollection` isn't in scope when you try to reference it in your callback.  SUGGESTION:  try moving it to the top of your class, below "const app = express();".  ALSO: this article might help: https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: @paulsm4 I've now declared **quotesCollection** in scope immediately below "const app = express();" as you've suggested and I'm now getting a new error "TypeError: quotesCollection.insertOne is not a function" I have also tried **quotesCollection.create.** Many thanks...

Comment: OK: your first problem was that "quotesCollection" wasn't in scope.  Your current problem is that "quotesCollection" isn't recognized as an object that has method "insertOne()".   SUGGESTIONS: 1) move the line `app.use(express.json())` toward the top, and 2) CRITICALLY - get rid of `const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes');`.  Declare "quotesCollection" at the top; then assign "quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes');" in your '.then", and finally reference it in your callback.  The local "const" is MASKING the global "quotesCollection" object with a LOCAL instance.

Answer (score 0):

HI I just came to know that You are doing wrong with data type on collection declaring const as it will update change behaviorally so put a let correct your app I declared on top with let By Mian Salman, SK Developers.
and success look.
[image]

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
// const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
let quotesCollection=null;
const connectionString = "mongodb+srv://skdevelopers:***useyourpass@cluster-pak.bwufncs.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
// const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(client => {
    console.log('Connected to Database')
    const db = client.db('star-wars-quotes')
     quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest on the client the '/quotes' post to fix the scope problem

```
.then(client => {
    console.log('Connected to Database');
    const db = client.db('star-wars-quotes'); 
    const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes');

    app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
        quotesCollection.insertOne(req.body)
        .then(result => {
           console.log(result);
         })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Note: If you have a problem with your IP, go to MongoDB and change your IP to 0.0.0.0/0